# Debian add all available IPv6 addresses

Tags: debian, ip, ipv6

I know it's possible to add singe IPv6 addresses to the system by calling this command:

```
ip -6 addr add 2002:c000:203::1/64 dev eth0
```

This works fine for single addresses. However if I want several of these I have to add them all manually. So my question is if there's a way to allow my system to bind/respond to all possible IPv6 addresses without having to manually enable them.
And if so how can I add this configuration in the `/etc/interfaces` file so that this configuration persists over a reboot of the system?